# Brackets (like tuple) around form fields

Tags: python, django

There is something wrong the way with I treat unicode in python. In Django, part of my model and code is shown below.

```
class MyTest(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s,%s' % (self.address, self.city)
```

I load these values through csv.

```
    records = csv.DictReader(self.cleaned_data["file"])
        for line in records:
            mt = MyTest()
            mt.address=line['ADDRESS'],
            mt.city=line['CITY'],
            ....
            mt.save()
            print line['ADDRESS']
            print mt.address


70 Mall Rd
('70 Mall Rd',)
```

The problem, in admin template all my values has the brackets around it. Like

```
('LARGO',), ('FL',),
```

what could be wrong.

thanks.

Comment: Remove the comma after `line['ADDRESS'],` and `line['CITY'],` and see if that helps.

Comment: When reading the file, specify a codec and decode the file in order to yield unicode objects instead of byte strings. if `self.city` and `self.address` are unicode objects, also `'%s,%s' % (self.address, self.city)` will be unicode (without the `u`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's tuples with one element, because you add comma in line `mt.address=line['ADDRESS'],` and `mt.city=line['CITY'],`

For example:

```
>>> True,
(True,)
>>> True
True
```